# Embedding framework in iOS generates an error when signing

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, codesign

I am currently trying to embed the Azure client framework into an iOS project, but the build is failing when it tries to sign the framework, with the following error:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gtoxtgdnkyheledfgmjhogvasnql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/Frameworks/AZSClient.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

After poking around on the web, I found this highly useful page:
https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlSignal/issues/16

The command being run by code sign is this:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none \
    --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags \
    ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gtoxtgdnkyheledfgmjhogvasnql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/Frameworks/AZSClient.framework
```

which generates the error I mentioned above.  Following Mat's lead and modifying the end of the command to point to the actual framework binary as follows:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none \
    --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags \
    ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gtoxtgdnkyheledfgmjhogvasnql/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/Frameworks/AZSClient.framework/AZSClient
```

the command correctly executes and signs the framework.

**My Question:** 
How do I modify the Xcode build system to do this.  If I try just building after running the code sign on the command line, it overwrites my code sign.  If I try building without signing the framework, it presents an unsigned version of the framework to the target (in this case the simulator).

Comment: What happens if you add `--deep` to the *Other Code Signing Flags* in the *Build Settings*?

Comment: I still get the same build error, and if I add the /AZSClient at the end it works.  I can see the option --deep has been added to the command line though...

Comment: For what it's worth, I found a "fix" for my problem, which was to sign the framework when it was being compiled.  If I didn't have the source for the framework though, I don't know what I would have done...